# c++ переопределение оператора + с использованием конструкции {x, y}

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, перегрузка-операторов, переопределение

Подскажите, можно ли реализовать следующую вещь:

Есть класс `CFraction` с конструктором `CFraction(int, int)`, что даёт возможность делать такую инициализацию:

```
const CFraction value = {1, 3};
```

Можно ли у класса `CFraction` переопределить оператор `+` так, чтобы можно было писать вот такой код:

```
const CFraction value2 = value + {2, 5};
```

?

Т.е. без каких либо явных преобразований типов

Comment: Прибавляйте `initializer_list` :)

Comment: @Harry, вот так не срабатывает: `CFraction operator + (const std::initializer_list<int>& value) const {return *this + CFraction(value);}` Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Гм. Похоже, тут какие-то хитрости. Вот такой вызов `CFraction<int> c = a.operator + ({1,2});` работает. Что-то тут хитрое с шаблонностью и поиском имен, как я понимаю... Надо бы гуру в этих вопросах поспрашивать...

Comment: @Harry Потому что `initializer_list` позволяет использовать себя при перегрузках в правой части только в `assignment-operator:  = *= *= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ^= |=`, но не в операторе в обычных операторах, каких как `+ - / ...`. Поэтому в данном случаем можно будет вызвать только одним из этих способов: `c = a.operator + ({1,2});`, `c = a + initializer_list<int>{1,2};`. То есть можно перегрузить `+=` с `initializer_list`, а вот `+` Нельзя

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev ХитрО, однако... А где это в стандарте прописано, не подскажете?

Comment: @Harry C++14 5.17 и 8.5.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, без явной типизации такая перегрузка невозможна.

Единственно, что можно сделать:

```
CFraction operator+=(initializer_list<int> values) const
    {
        ...
    }
```

И вы можете получить желаемый результат в 2 шага:

1. `value += {2, 5}`
2. `value2 = value`

Перегрузка `+` возможна, но так, как выше описал **Harry**:

```
CFraction operator+ (initializer_list<int> values) {
        ...
    }
```

, но придется обращаться одним из двух методов:

1. `value2 = value.operator + ({1,2});`
2. `value2 = value + initializer_list<int>{1,2};`

Это обуславливается стандартом C++14 (параграфы 5.17 и 8.5.4 ), где пишется, что `initializer_list` в правой части выражения может применяться только к операторам `assignment-operator: = *= /= %= += -= >>= <<= &= ˆ= |=`

Comment: Для `+=` вместо `initializer_list` можно использовать просто `CFraction`, и такая запись все равно будет работать (ну если есть не-explicit конструктор с 2 параметрами).

Comment: HollyBlackCat, не получается :( - `C2679 binary '+=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'initializer list' (or there is no acceptable conversion)` при наличии конструктора `CFraction(const int numenator, const int denumenator)`, что позволяет делать `CFraction value = {1, 2}`